# Efficient way to choose random element from list based on length

Tags: python

Apologies if this is the wrong forum - it's my first question. I'm learning python and writing a password generator as an exercise from www.practicepython.org

I've written the following but it can be really slow so I guess i"m doing it inefficiently. I want to select a random word from the dictionary and then add ascii characters to it. I want at least 2 ascii characters in the password so I use a while loop to ensure that the word element contains (length - 2).

This works fine if you say that you want the password to be 10 characters long, but if you constrict to something like 5 I think the while loop has to go through so many iterations it can take up to 30 seconds.

I can't find the answer via searching - guidance appreciated!

```
import string
import random
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import words

word = words.words()[random.randint(1, len(words.words()))]
ascii_str = (string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation)

length = int(input("How long do you want the password to be? "))

while len(word) >= (length - 2):
    word = words.words()[random.randint(1, len(words.words()))]

print("The password is: " + word, end="")

for i in range(0, (length - len(word))):
    print(ascii_str[random.randint(1, len(ascii_str) - 1)], end="")
```

Comment: Instead of repeating choosing a random word until its length is by chance what you need, you should organize your words by length, so when you need to make a random pick, you just make one random pick from within the words which have the desired length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by calling `words.words()` just *once* and store that in a variable:

```
allwords = words.words()
```

That saves a lot of work, because now the `nltk.corpus` library won't try to load the whole list each time you try to get the length of the list or try to select a random word with the index you generated.

Next, use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.choice) to pick a random element from that list. That eliminates the need to keep passing in a list length:

```
word = random.choice(allwords)

# ...

while len(word) >= (length - 2):
    word = random.choice(allwords)
```

Next, you could group the words by length first:

```
allwords = words.words()
by_length = {}
for word in allwords:
    by_length.setdefault(len(word), []).append(word)
```

This gives you a dictionary with keys representing the length of the words; the nltk corpus has words between 1 and 24 letters long. Each value in the dictionary is a list of words of the same length, so `by_length[12]` would give you a list of words that are all exactly 12 characters long.

This allows you to pick words of a specific length:

```
# start with the desired length, and see if there are words this long in the
# dictionary, but don’t presume that all possible lengths exist:
wordlength = length - 2
while wordlength > 0 and wordlength not in by_length:
    wordlength -= 1

# we picked a length, but it could be 0, -1 or -2, so start with an empty word
# and then pick a random word from the list with words of the right length.
word = ''
if wordlength > 0:
    word = random.choice(by_length[wordlength])
```

Now `word` is the longest random word that'll fit your criteria: at least 2 characters shorter than the required length, and taken at random from the word list.

More importantly: we only picked a random word **once**. Provided you keep the `by_length` dictionary around for longer and re-use it in a password-generating function, that's a big win.

Picking the nearest available length from `by_length` can be done without stepping through every possible length one step at a time if you use [bisection](https://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html), but I’ll leave adding that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: That's great, thank you!! Works really well, and gives me a lot to look into and learn form. The challenges I will move onto on my own now are: limit the length of the word to ensure enough ascii characters, ensure each password has a word, upper case, lower case and special character.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice)
From the docs:

> random.choice(seq)
>   Return a random element from the non-empty sequence seq.

```
In [22]: import random                                                                                                                                

In [23]: random.choice([1,2,3,4,5])                                                                                                                   
Out[23]: 3

In [24]: random.choice([1,2,3,4,5])                                                                                                                   
Out[24]: 5

In [25]: random.choice([1,2,3,4,5])                                                                                                                   
Out[25]: 1
```

The code can then be simplified to

```
import string
import random
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import words

#All words assigned to a list first
words = words.words()

#Get a random word
word = random.choice(words)
ascii_str = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation

length = int(input("How long do you want the password to be? "))

while len(word) >= (length - 2):
    word = random.choice(words)

#Use random.sample to choose n random samples, and join them all to make a string
password = word + ''.join(random.sample(ascii_str, length))
print("The password is: " + password, end="")
```

Possible outputs are

```
How long do you want the password to be? 10
The password is: heyT{7<XEVc!l
How long do you want the password to be? 8
The password is: hiBk-^8t7]
```

But ofcourse, this is not an optimized solution as noted by @MartjinPieters in the comment, but I will try to provide something along the lines as he pointed in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55993182/8591431), in a different way as follows

- I will use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to create the by_length dictionary, a dictionary with key as word length and values as list of words of that length using itertools.groupby
- I will ensure a minimum length restriction for length of password
- Use random.sample to choose pass_len random samples, and join them all to make a string, and append the word in front!

```
import string
import random
from itertools import groupby

#All words assigned to a list first
words = ['a', 'c', 'e', 'bc', 'def', 'ghij' , 'jklmn']

#Get a random word
word = random.choice(words)
ascii_str = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation

#Check for minimum length, and exit the code if it is not
min_length = 8
pass_len = int(input("How long do you want the password to be? Minimum length is {}".format(min_length)))

if pass_len <= min_length:
    print('Password is not long enough')
    exit()

#Create the by_length dictionary, a dictionary with key as word length and values as list of words of that length using itertools.groupby
by_length = {}
for model, group in groupby(words, key=len):
    by_length[model] = list(group)

chosen_word = ''
req_len = pass_length - 2

#Iterate till you find the word of required length of pass_len - 2, else reduce the required length by 1
while req_len > 0:
    if req_len in words:
        chosen_word = by_length[req_len]
    else:
        req_len -= 1

#Use random.sample to choose n random samples, and join them all to make a string
password = word + ''.join(random.sample(ascii_str, length))
print("The password is: " + password, end="")
```

Comment: The method used is not the only reason their code is slow however!

Comment: Yes, I noted that in the answer, and if I can come up with another optimized version better than yours @MartijnPieters I will leave the comment there :)

Comment: Thank you Devesh - really helpful answer and has given me a lot to think about and work on for myself.

Comment: Great! Glad to help! Since you already chose another answer it would be great if you could upvote my answer when you have enough reputation :)